# RSpec not recognizing deleted association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, faker

In my rails application, a user has many baskets, and a basket belongs to a user. The User class also contains an instance method that removes the user's id from all associated baskets. I am having issues testing that method using RSpec, FactoryGirl and Faker.

```
class Basket
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
end

class User
  has_many: baskets

  def disassociate_baskets
    baskets.each { |b| b.update(user: nil) }
  end
end
```

The `disassociate_baskets` method works with real data, my RSpec test fails because in the test environment because the basket-user association persists even after running the method. Here's my testing code:

```
#Basket Factory
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :basket do
    date { Faker::Date.backward }
  end
end

#User Factory
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name { Faker::Name.name }
  end
end

#user_spec.rb
describe "When deleting purchase history" do
  before do
    @user = create(:user)
    @user1 = create(:user)
    @basket = create(:basket, user: @user)
    @basket1 = create(:basket, user: @user)
    @basket2 = create(:basket, user: @user1)
  end

  it "disassociates the user from the basket" do
    @user.disassociate_baskets
    expect(@basket.user).to eq nil
  end
end
```

I've inspected the objects inside the `it` block, and they are fine, but @basket is still associated to @user even after running disassociate_baskets method, so my test fails. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Possible solution:**

```
expect(@basket.reload.user).to eq nil
```

**Why you need to reload it:**

When you create the new basket and assign it to `@basket`, it will have an associated `User` assigned to it. Then, you call `@user.disassociate_baskets`, which loops over all the baskets of that user by **instantiating them one by one**, and updating their `user` attribute.

But since `@user.disassociate_baskets` instantiated brand new `Basket` instances, the `user` attribute will be set to `nil` only in these new instances. `@basket` has no idea that another instance got modified, and has to be reloaded manually.